# Using variable as a dictionary key to argument, when including file in Mako

Tags: python, dictionary, cherrypy, mako

I have a web page, created with CherryPy and Mako combo. I'm trying to include a file and I want to use a dictionary to pass an argument to the file. It gives a following error:

```
KeyError: '${job}'
```

My main program, where jobs is a dictionary. job_shortnames and branches are lists.

```
return tmpl.render(jobs = job_results, job_shortnames = job_shortnames, branches=branches)
```

And from my index.html

```
% for short_name in job_shortnames:
    <tr>
        <th class="testName"> ${short_name} </th>
             % for branch in branches:
                <% job = branch+"_"+short_name %>
                <%include file="job.html" args="te=jobs['${job}'], logfile='Foo'"/>
             % endfor
     </tr>
% endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've just got a typo.  you want...

```
${jobs}
```

cause:

```
return tmpl.render(jobs= job_results, job_shortnames = job_shortnames, branches=branches)
```

Hope this helps!